# "The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request" on disconnecting serial

Tags: c#, exception, serial-port

I am writing a program to read data from serial and display it. Sometimes (not every time) it crashes when I disconnect serial with the exception `The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request`. (I guess something is wrong here even it happens not every time).

Here is how I am reading serial:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // this line below is where the exception is
    string read = _serialPort.ReadLine().Replace(".", ",").Split('\r')[0];
}

// clicking on a button opens/closes serial
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isSerialConnected)
        disconnectSerial();
    else
        connectSerial();
}

public void connectSerial()
{
    _serialPort.PortName = serialCombobox.SelectedItem.ToString();
    _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
    _serialPort.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(this.serialPort1_DataReceived);
    _serialPort.Open();

    serialCombobox.Enabled = false;
    connectSerialButton.Text = "disconnect";

    isSerialConnected = true;
}

public void disconnectSerial()
{
   _serialPort.Close();

    serialCombobox.Enabled = true;
    connectSerialButton.Text = "connect";

    isSerialConnected = false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's not possible, the SerialPort.Close() call is interlocked with the DataReceived event handler.  Close() cannot progress when the event handler is still running.  Crystal ball say that you *actually* jerked the USB connector by hand.  Never do this, always go through the Safely Remove Hardware tray icon.  Unclear *why* you do this, pulling the plug never fixes a deadlock.  Instead fix your event handler and never call Invoke(), always BeginInvoke().  Also keep in mind that ReadLine() is risky if communications are unreliable or interrupted if you don't set the ReadTimeout property.

Comment: @HansPassant nope, I didn't unplugged it, I just hit connect/disconnect serial button in my app many times and eventually the exception happens

Comment: @HansPassant and I didn't use Invoke() in my handler, I used only BeginInvoke to run some code in main thread, but anyway, if I'll comment out this code, the exception is thrown anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed it this way, and now this kinda works.

```
try
{
    read = _serialPort.ReadLine().Replace(".", ",").Split('\r')[0];
}
catch (System.IO.IOException error)
{
    return;
}
catch (System.InvalidOperationException error)
{
    return;
}
```

There were 2 kind of errors that happened, IOException with the message that is on the question's title, and InvalidOperationException, with the message "The port is closed". In both cases we'll just return and not process the data.

I'm not sure that it is the way it should be done, but anyway, it kinda works.

Answer (score 3):

You read data from the serial port in an event handler. From [SerialPort.ReadLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readline(v=vs.110).aspx):

> By default, the ReadLine method will block until a line is received.

So when you close the serial port, it is possible you are still waiting to receive a line. But you cannot receive data if the port is closed, so an Exception is thrown because it is not possible any more to receive a line.

Comment: So how should I handle this? I guess that I can wrap it in a try/catch statement and do nothing in catch block, but something tells me this is not how it should be done.

Comment: In your example you don't use the result of the `ReadLine` anyway, so an empty catch would be ok. You probably don't want an `UnhandledException`  event. If you are able to handle the exception in a useful way, that is always better. I would at least recommend to log the exception to help future diagnostics. However, the comment of Hans Passant above is interesting. It would suggest my answer is wrong. Or maybe there is a bug somewhere else (in a driver?).

Comment: actually I use it later, I just commented it out to see if that line with the ReadLine() is actually the cause of the exception

Answer (score 0):

When you get data from `SerialPort.ReadLine()` in your `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler`
you must check serial port is open.

For example:

```
if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
{
  return;
}

string read = _serialPort.ReadLine().Replace(".", ",").Split('\r')[0];
```